# Parse "take it easy" "take it seriously"?

Tags: parsing

In "take it easy", "easy" is an adjective.
In "take it seriously", "seriously" is an adverb.

I'm baffled. Why not "take it easily"? Using an adverb to modify the verb makes more sense.

For the same reason, I should say "take it more slowly", instead of "take it slower", right?

Comment: Here *easy* is an adverb which means [*in a relaxed or casual manner*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/easy#Adverb).

Comment: People would also say "take it slow".

Comment: Thanks for all help at this site. Now I know "easy" "slow" are "flat adverbs." I googled and understood more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some words can be multiple parts of speech.

**easy** is an adjective, an adverb, and an exclamation.

So to know which of those parts of speech you should be using, you have to inspect the word in the context of the sentence.